# Parse column B content into logical parts according to column A

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this

```
sessionId  |   hostname
------     |   ------
a1         |   domain1
a1         |   domain2
a2         |   domain1
a3         |   domain1
a3         |   domain2
a4         |   domain2
```

What I want is to build a logical table containing the follwoing

```
sessionId  |   only domain1 | only domain2 | domain1 OR domain2 | domain1 AND domain2 
-----------|----------------|--------------|--------------------|--------------------
a1         |   1            | 1            | 1                  | 1
a2         |   1            | 0            | 1                  | 0
a3         |   1            | 1            | 1                  | 1
a4         |   0            | 1            | 1                  | 0
```

I guess there's a simple solution for this, but I can't get my head over it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select (case when sum(case when hostname = 'domain1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as domain1,
       (case when sum(case when hostname = 'domain2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as domain2,
       (case when sum(case when hostname = 'domain1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
                  sum(case when hostname = 'domain2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as either,
       (case when sum(case when hostname = 'domain1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when hostname = 'domain2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as both          
from t
group by sessionid;
```

Comment: I wonder, if there's a shorter approach... Perhaps, using "IF" function

Comment: `case` is ANSI standard; `if` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Declare @Table as Table (sessionId varchar(100),hostname varchar(100))
Insert into @Table Values
('a1','domain1'),
('a1','domain2'),
('a2','domain1'),
('a3','domain1'),
('a3','domain2'),
('a4','domain2')

Select distinct T.sessionId,
case when s1.sessionid is null then 0 else 1 end [only domain1],
case when s2.sessionid is null then 0 else 1 end [only domain2],
case when 
(
case when s1.sessionid is null then 0 else 1 end = 1 or 
case when s2.sessionid is null then 0 else 1 end = 1
) then 1 else 0 end [domain1 OR domain2],
case when 
(
case when s1.sessionid is null then 0 else 1 end = 1 and 
case when s2.sessionid is null then 0 else 1 end = 1
) then 1 else 0 end [domain1 AND domain2]
 from @Table T
Left Join
(
Select sessionId From @Table where hostname = 'domain1'
) s1 on s1.sessionId = T.sessionId 
Left Join
(
Select sessionId From @Table where hostname = 'domain2'
) s2 on s2.sessionId = T.sessionId
```

Answer (score 1):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  sessionId, 
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain1')) only_domain1, 
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain2')) only_domain2, 
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain1')+COUNTIF(hostname='domain2')) domain1_or_domain2,
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain1')*COUNTIF(hostname='domain2')) domain1_and_domain2
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` 
GROUP BY sessionId
```

you can test / play with it using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'a1' sessionId, 'domain1' hostname UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1', 'domain2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a2', 'domain1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a3', 'domain1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a3', 'domain2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a4', 'domain2' 
)
SELECT 
  sessionId, 
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain1')) only_domain1, 
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain2')) only_domain2, 
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain1')+COUNTIF(hostname='domain2')) domain1_or_domain2,
  SIGN(COUNTIF(hostname='domain1')*COUNTIF(hostname='domain2')) domain1_and_domain2
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` 
GROUP BY sessionId 
ORDER BY sessionId
```

Comment: Mikhail! Nice and slick, as always. Thanks a lot!